# Adding passive event listener Polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer-2.x

I am trying to add passive gesture event listener to a Polymer Element.
As per the specification:
"Applications can call Polymer.setPassiveTouchGestures(true) to force all event listeners for gestures to be passive. 
       You must call setPassiveTouchGestures before adding any gesture event listeners" 
Hence I added the following code:

```js
      constructor ()
      {
        Polymer.setPassiveTouchGestures(true);
        super();
              
      }
```

In the ***app.html file
Then I registered for events using

```js
Polymer.Gestures.addListener(this.$.view1, 'track', e => this.handleTrackView1(e));
```

handleTrackView1 gets called but the browser stops handling events.
Any idea what else should I modify apart from adding passive touch gesture.

Answer (score 0):

Despite setting gesture to passive need to call
Polymer.Gestures.setTouchAction(this,"auto"); post registering for 
addListener.